# Send stream of Data from client program (running in VM) to server program(on Host OS) using socket programming in Java

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, bufferedreader, data-stream

A Client socket Program (in windows VM) generates integer from 1 to 10 as per below code

```
public class ClientSocket {

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {

try{
    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    String clientIP = inetAddress.getHostAddress();
    System.out.println("Client IP address " + clientIP);

   Integer dataSendingPort ;
   dataSendingPort = 6999 ;

    Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.32",dataSendingPort);
    String WelcomeMessage = " hello server from " + clientIP ;


 BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

 if(socket.isConnected()){
     System.out.println("connection was successful");
 }
 else{
     System.out.println("Error- connection was not successful");
 }


 for (int x= 0 ; x< 10 ; x++){
     bufferedWriter.write(x);
     bufferedWriter.flush();
 }

    bufferedWriter.close();
}
catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println(e);
}// catch
        finally{

    System.out.println("closing connection");

}

    } // main

} // class
```

My server socket program is running on Mac OS as Host Machine, whose code is shown below

```
 public class MyServer {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


           try {
// get input data by connecting to the socket


                InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                String ServerIP = inetAddress.getHostAddress();

               System.out.println("\n server IP address = " + ServerIP);

               Integer ListeningPort ;
               ListeningPort = 6999 ;

               ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(ListeningPort);

               System.out.println("server is receiving data on port # "+ ListeningPort +"\n");

               // waiting for connection form client

               Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();


               if(socket.isConnected()){

                   System.out.println("Connection was successful");
               }
               else {
                   System.out.println("connection was not successful");
               }



              BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    Integer s = 0 ;

       while (( s = input.read()) >= 0){

           System.out.println(input.read());
       }
           } //try

            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);

            } // catch


        } //main
    } //socket class
```

The issue is that output I am receiving is -1 when I use while loop and receive first value i.e 0 without using a loop.

> However, I was able to send a single value from client to server, but
>   how can I send Stream of Values from the client and print it on Server
>   Side.

Suggestions are most welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- -1 means end of stream.
- Closing the input or output stream of a stock closes the socket.
- `socket.isConnected()` cannot possibly be false at the point you are testing it.
- `input.ready()` isn't a test for end of stream, or end of message, or end of transmission, or anything useful at all really.
- Don't flush inside loops.